# Link in Rails doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using Rails 4 and Devise 3.4.1

I have two pages. One of these two pages should not be accessed by unauthenticated users. I have a nav bar in the home page in which a link to that dashboard page is listed.

This is the link

```
<li><a href="/pages/dashboard/">Dashboard</a></li>
```

In order to prevent unauthenticated access to that page, I fixed the pages controller as follows:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def dashboard
    if user_signed_in?
      render "dashboard"
    else
      render "home"
    end
  end

end
```

So far so good. This works for me, and I'm happy. When I manually type in the address bar the following:

```
localhost:3000/pages/dashboard
```

In case I am signed in as a user, the page shows up, in case I'm not, then I will be redirected to the home page.

Now, my problem is with the link up there. It doesn't work! How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: So the link was working and suddenly it does not work? Explain what changes you made before this had happened.

Comment: That's alright, I fixed it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I fixed it. I used the following:

```
<li><%= link_to "Dashboard", "/pages/dashboard", method: :get %></li>
```

Instead of:

```
<li><a href="/pages/dashboard/">Dashboard</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use "user_signed_in?" in a controller I am pretty sure you need to use Devise's before_filter in that same controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. This will redirect me to the  /user/sign_in page, but I want the user to be redirected to the home page where I have moved my sign in form to.

Comment: If you could suggest me another way I could redirect the user to the root instead of user/sign_in, I would REALLY appreciate it. I wanted to overwrite this in the sessions controller but I wasn't sure how, because I tried the user_redirect but it didn't work for me. I then found that method which did the trick for me.